# I am trying to return a single row per record, but am receiving multiple

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql

I am trying to query a table. The table contains a barcode and activity related to the barcode, specifically when it is moved and where. I am trying to return one record per barcode containing the last date and time it was moved along with the location. I currently have MAX around both move date and time. Here is a sample of the duplicated rows.

```
BarCode       Location  Date           Time
000055279 1   EWC       03-APR-14      12:30:44  
000055279 1   G-T       05-AUG-14      08:16:10  
000055279 1   TBD       20-AUG-14      08:32:14
```

I only want the last row in this example (`000055279 1   TBD      20-AUG-14      08:32:14`). Current query is basically:

```
SELECT DISTINCT "BarCode", "Location", MAX("Date"), MAX("Time")
FROM TABLE1
```

As soon as I add the Location, the duplicates happen.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You definitively should use proper _date_ (`DATE` or `TIMESTAMP`) column to store date time values. Using two columns here is a source of error: `MAX("Date"), MAX("Time")` is not necessary what you think...

Comment: Are you using Oracle?  The answers so far assume that; probably due to the plsql Tag.  I suggest adding the appropriate database software tag.

Comment: Unfortunately, it is a vendor database, they store DATE and TIME separately, TIME as a number, that can be between 1 and 6 characters. I had to use a CASE to get it into the format you see in the sample. The second vendor, that I am doing the export for, wants DATE and TIME separate and formatted as shown in the example. Added Oracle tag.

Answer (score 3):

There are several options for this.  One is to use `row_number()`:

```
select *
from (
    select barcode, location, date, time, 
           row_number() over (partition by barcode order by date desc, time desc) rn
    from table1
) t
where rn = 1
```

Comment: This appears to be working, I'll have to verify more data to be sure. Thanks, I should be on the right track now.

Answer (score 2):

Based on your idea, but fixing a flaw in the design, you could (re)generate the correct *datetime* column using a CTE, and then query that view:

> ```
> WITH V AS (SELECT "BarCode", "Location",
>                   TO_DATE("Date"|| ' ' || "Time", 'DD-MON-YY HH:MI:SS') "datetime"
>            FROM TABLE1)
>
>
> SELECT "BarCode", "Location", MAX("datetime")
> FROM V
> GROUP BY "BarCode", "Location"
> ```
>
> <sup>Untested. Beware of typos!</sup>

---

That being said, as of myself, I would push toward having only one `DATE` column in the table. If it is not feasible for some reason, maybe you could propose to add a virtual column instead:

```
ALTER TABLE TABLE1
ADD ("datetime" DATE GENERATED ALWAYS 
             AS (TO_DATE("Date"|| ' ' || "Time", 'DD-MON-YY HH:MI:SS')) VIRTUAL);
```

Comment: I can't edit the table, it is a vendor database, so I would violate our maintenance contract. Additionally, I have to keep the DATE and TIME separate, as the second vendor requesting the export wants it in that format.

Answer (score 0):

The Oracle ROW_NUMBER analytic function is what you need.  The [Oracle documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/functions123.htm) explains it well and here's a worked example using your data plus some additional barcodes to illustrate it working across a more realistic data set. I'm concatenating the date & time columns and using TO_DATE to get a proper date.  Since these are reserved words they are enclosed in double quotes.

```
SQL> create table barcode_activity (
  2  barcode varchar2(20),
  3  location varchar2(10),
  4  "date"  varchar2(10),
  5  "time"  varchar2(10)
  6  );

Table created.

SQL> 
SQL> insert into barcode_activity
  2  values
  3  ( '000055279 1','EWC', '03-APR-14','12:30:44')
  4  
SQL> insert into barcode_activity
  2  values
  3  ( '000055279 1','G-T', '05-APR-14','08:16:10');

1 row created.

SQL> 
SQL> insert into barcode_activity
  2  values
  3  ( '000055279 1','TBD', '20-APR-14', '08:32:14');

1 row created.

SQL> 
SQL> insert into barcode_activity
  2  values
  3  ( '000009999 1','TBD', '20-APR-14', '07:42:32');

1 row created.

SQL> 
SQL> insert into barcode_activity
  2  values
  3  ( '000001234 1','TBD', '29-APR-14', '17:22:18');

1 row created.

SQL> 
SQL> insert into barcode_activity
  2  values
  3  ( '000001234 1','TBD', '29-APR-14', '17:22:18');

1 row created.

SQL> 
SQL> insert into barcode_activity
  2  values
  3  ( '000001234 1','TBD', '29-APR-14', '17:22:18');

1 row created.

SQL> commit;

Commit complete.

SQL> 
SQL> SELECT * FROM barcode_activity ORDER BY 1,2,3;

BARCODE          LOCATION   date       time
-------------------- ---------- ---------- ----------
000001234 1      TBD    29-APR-14  17:22:18
000001234 1      TBD    29-APR-14  17:22:18
000001234 1      TBD    29-APR-14  17:22:18
000009999 1      TBD    20-APR-14  07:42:32
000055279 1      G-T    05-APR-14  08:16:10
000055279 1      TBD    20-APR-14  08:32:14

6 rows selected.

SQL> 
SQL> /* rank solution
SQL>    this will return one row
SQL>    for all barcodes in the table where there are collisions in rank th
SQL>    multiple rows are returned 
SQL>   */
SQL> SELECT barcode, location, "date", "time"
  2  FROM
  3          (SELECT barcode,
  4              location,
  5              "date",
  6              "time",
  7              RANK() OVER (
  8                PARTITION BY barcode
  9                ORDER BY TO_DATE("date"||' '||"time",'DD-MON-YYYY HH24:MI:SS') DESC
 10                ) AS activity_order
 11          FROM barcode_activity)
 12  WHERE activity_order = 1;

BARCODE          LOCATION   date       time
-------------------- ---------- ---------- ----------
000001234 1      TBD    29-APR-14  17:22:18
000001234 1      TBD    29-APR-14  17:22:18
000001234 1      TBD    29-APR-14  17:22:18
000009999 1      TBD    20-APR-14  07:42:32
000055279 1      TBD    20-APR-14  08:32:14

SQL> 
SQL> /* row_number solution - works regardless of collisions    */
SQL> SELECT barcode, location, "date", "time"
  2  FROM
  3          (SELECT barcode,
  4              location,
  5              "date",
  6              "time",
  7              row_number() OVER (
  8                PARTITION BY barcode
  9                ORDER BY TO_DATE("date"||' '||"time",'DD-MON-YYYY HH24:MI:SS') DESC
 10                ) AS activity_order
 11          FROM barcode_activity)
 12  WHERE activity_order = 1;

BARCODE          LOCATION   date       time
-------------------- ---------- ---------- ----------
000001234 1      TBD    29-APR-14  17:22:18
000009999 1      TBD    20-APR-14  07:42:32
000055279 1      TBD    20-APR-14  08:32:14
```

Comment: `RANK` can produce ties. If you need to guarantee that only a single row is returned, `ROW_NUMBER` is the better choice.

Comment: In the table you created, you gave the same value for location to all three rows, but they are different in the sample I provided. Will this still work? Also, I can't combine DATE and TIME, will this matter?

Comment: I did miss that the location changed in your example but this won't affect the result.  The record with rank 1 based on the activity_date will be returned.

Comment: with regard to alan's comment regarding ties - it is true that if two rows had the exact same date and time then then two rows would be returned.  This may or may not be a valid scenario.  Having a unique constraint across these columns would avoid that.

Comment: Updated original answer with improvements.  If you need to get all the latest entries for all barcodes in one go then the RANK is the way to go.  If you are querying one barcode at a time then the rownum solution may work for you.  It would be much slower to query each barcode separately then to do it all at once.

Comment: I see the light Allan was right all along. The Analytic function ROW_NUMBER is the better solution.  Example updated.